# Throttling HTML5 Video currentTime

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, html5-video

I have an app that tracks video views and integrates it with other marketing activities. In doing so, I needed to keep track of how long a person watches a html5 video and post it back to my app (via an API). I'm using [videojs](http://www.videojs.com) player, but really this is just a wrapper around the HTML5's api for this attribute. This is in an app with various videos can be loaded based on what page they are watching, so I needed a solution that tracked regardless of video length.

The problem I had, as a video plays the **API reports back every ~300MS** and I didn't want to hit my API that often. So I needed a solution to keep track of last time I posted. After digging around, I couldn't find an answer, so in case someone else with a similar need, my solution to this problem is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've decided that I wanted to post my video viewing results every 5 seconds, but since we have no guarantee that the currentTime will report back at exactly 5 seconds, so we just need to round to closest whole integer value.

On my video wrapper div, I've added a data attribute called data-last-time-push. I post the rounded time every time I push and check to see if we have exceed the interval before we post again.

### HTML

```
<div id="video-wrapper" data-time-last-push="0">
```

### Javascript

Bind the videojs container to the timeupdate property.

```
    var vid = videojs("video-container", {}, function() {
        this.on('timeupdate', videoTracker);
    });
```

### function for posting ajax...

```
var videoTracker = function() {
    var player = this;
    var last_push, wrapper, current;
    wrapper = $('#video-wrapper');
    last_push = wrapper.attr("data-time-last-push");
    current = Math.round(player.currentTime());
    //you could make the 5 here to be a variable or your own interval...
    if (current%5 === 0) {
        if (current > last_push) {
            //do your AJAX post here...
            wrapper.attr("data-time-last-push", current);
            console.log('currentTime = ' + player.currentTime());
            console.log(' duration: ' + player.duration());
        }
    }
};
```

Note, I tried to do a jsfiddle to show it working, but ended up running into HTTPS videos because the sample videos don't work through secure connections.

Comment: You probably want to chop the decimal value of `current` first, something like `if (!(current>>>0) % 5) {...}` This will give you whole integer seconds to check against. And of course, update last_push so that you don't get 25/30 checks per second. Or it may not be necessary since current will always have a clean start on a second (except maybe with NTSC 29.97 based video depending on how the browser handle it). Just a thought anyways.. :)